# Writing a (scraped) list of dataframes to single excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape an HTML table off a list of webpages (there's only one table on each page).

Here's the first part of my code:

```
for i in range(len(urls)):
  r = requests.get(urls[i], header)
  data = pd.read_html(r.text,index_col=0, header=0) 
  appended_list.append(data)
```

'urls' is a list of urls (each of which have one static table)
This code works - I get a list of dataframes (appended_list).

Now, I want to write this list of dataframes into a single excel sheet. This is what I've tried -

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')   
row = 0

for df in appended_list:
  df.to_excel(writer,startrow=row,startcol=0)   
  row = row + len(df.index) + 1

writer.save()
```

I get the error:

```
    df.to_excel(writer,startrow=row,startcol=0)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

What seems to be happening is that each element (dataframe) of the appended_list is still being read as a list. How do convert each of these list items to a dataframe so that they can be written on an excel file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Thank you @AMC! I used to code I've long since forgotten the 'good practices' guide. The steps mentioned in your post are very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p.read_html reads HTML tables into a list of DataFram objects.  You are then storing those lists in the list appended_list.

If you are sure you are getting only one dataframe from each url you could try:

```
for i in range(len(urls)):
  r = requests.get(urls[i], header)
  data = pd.read_html(r.text,index_col=0, header=0) 
  appended_list.append(data[0])
```

notice data[0] on line 4

Alternatively if it is possible that you have more than one dataframe from each page you could use extend instead of append.

```
for i in range(len(urls)):
  r = requests.get(urls[i], header)
  data = pd.read_html(r.text,index_col=0, header=0) 
  appended_list.extend(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each element of the appended_list is in itself a list according to the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html
If there is indeed only one DataFrame in each of those lists, you an do :

```
df = pd.concat([l[0] for l in appended_list])
df.to_excel(writer)
```

That avoids looping on the list and saving each time by concatenating all of the dataframes into one